# Unable to work py2exe

Tags: python, py2exe

I tried a lot of way but most code i did for example print "f" worked well. i not sure why my code does not work in exe. Below is the error i get

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
    windows=[{'script': 'hello.py'}],
    options={
        'py2exe': 
        {
            'includes': ['lxml.etree', 'lxml._elementpath', 'gzip'],
        }
    }
)
```

[image]

Error i got hello.exe.log

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "hello.py", line 25, in <module>
File "matplotlib\__init__.pyc", line 765, in <module>
File "matplotlib\__init__.pyc", line 683, in rc_params
File "matplotlib\__init__.pyc", line 599, in matplotlib_fname
File "matplotlib\__init__.pyc", line 246, in wrapper
File "matplotlib\__init__.pyc", line 520, in _get_data_path_cached
File "matplotlib\__init__.pyc", line 516, in _get_data_path
RuntimeError: Could not find the matplotlib data files
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "hello.py", line 25, in <module>
File "matplotlib\__init__.pyc", line 765, in <module>
File "matplotlib\__init__.pyc", line 683, in rc_params
File "matplotlib\__init__.pyc", line 599, in matplotlib_fname
File "matplotlib\__init__.pyc", line 246, in wrapper
File "matplotlib\__init__.pyc", line 520, in _get_data_path_cached
File "matplotlib\__init__.pyc", line 516, in _get_data_path
RuntimeError: Could not find the matplotlib data files
```

## This is all the LIB i used, is it some library doesnt work well with py2exe?

```
###### IMPORT STATEMENTS ######################################
import csv
import webbrowser
import heapq
from math import floor
import os
from os.path import basename, splitext
import re
from scipy import *
import string
import sys
from time import sleep
import time
import zipfile

from StringIO import StringIO
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as Tk
import lxml.etree as et
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle, Circle, RegularPolygon
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import NullFormatter
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as AA
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
import pylab as pl
import pylab as plot
from scipy.integrate import simps
import tkFileDialog
from tkFont import Font
import tkMessageBox
from scipy import interpolate
import pylab as py
import sys
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known problem with py2exe, see http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/MatPlotLib

When creating the bundle py2exe requires you to specify any external file that will be needed.

If you're looking for something more automatic take a look at [pyinstaller](http://pyinstaller.org) project (where many common libraries are already handled - not by magic, but because authors and contributors already took care to specify which external files are needed for a lot of commonly used python libraries).

Comment: How can i add all those specify external file in when i not sure which one is actually needed >.< sorry i am a newbie in python programming.. @6502

Comment: @ZhenHui: There's no easy solution for this problem. In an ideal world library authors would specify all runtime dependencies explicitly in a way that allows a packaging software to create a working bundle. Current solution of pyinstaller of working the other way around (i.e. having the packaging software knowing all libraries) is IMO much harder: pyinstaller is the kind of software that is fantastic to use (most of the times just works) and a nightmare to write and maintain. Py2exe solution is to drop the burden on end users.